# Why does $# always return 0?

Tags: bash, arguments

I'm trying to write a script that will only accept exactly one argument. I'm still learning so I don't understand what's wrong with my code. I don't understand why, even though I change the number of inputs the code just exits. (Note: I'm going to use $dir for later if then statements but I haven't included it.)

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "Specify the name of the directory"
read dir
if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
        echo "Script requires one and only one argument"
        exit
fi
```

Comment: Why are you prompting before checking the number of arguments?  How are you invoking this script?  What happens if you remove the prompt and `read` operation?  What do you think `$#` tests?

Comment: Side note: instead of echo/read, `bash` lets you do it all in one: `read -r -p "prompt text here " dir`

Comment: Is there's a misunderstanding at play here? `$#` has nothing to do with `read` - it's the number of arguments to the whole script. If you run `./foo.bash aye "bee bee" cee` then `$#` will be equal to 3 in the script. At the first or the last line of the script, unless you overwrite the argument list using for example `set` or `shift`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://www.shellcheck.net/ to double check your syntax.

`$#` tells you how many arguments the script was called with.
Here you have two options.

---

**Option 1**: Use arguments

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $# -ne 1 ]]
then
    echo "Script requires one and only one argument"
    exit 1
else
    echo "ok, arg1 is $1"
fi
```

- To call the script do: `./script.bash argument`
- Use `[[ ]]` for testing conditions (http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031)
- `exit 1`: by default when a script exists with a 0 status code, it means it worked ok.  Here since it is an error, specify a non-zero value.

---

**Option 2**: Do not use arguments, ask the user for a value.
*Note*: this version does not use arguments at all.

```
#!/bin/bash

read -r -p "Specify the name of the directory: " dir
if [[ ! -d "$dir" ]]
then
    echo "Error, directory $dir does not exist."
    exit 1
else
    echo "ok, directory $dir exists."
fi
```

- To call the script do: `./script.bash` without any arguments.

You should research bash tutorials to learn how to use arguments.